# Proper use of "was" vs "is"

Tags: grammaticality

Which is correct;

> The document was already posted

or

> The document is already posted

Answer (score 3):

Both are grammatically correct. The difference is the shade of meaning:

- *was already posted* emphasizes that the *action of posting* it was completed.
- *is already posted* emphasizes that the document *is currently available* and has been available since its posting.

Thus, the choice of phrasing depends on the communication intent of the speaker.