# Immunizations are complete or immunizations are completed

Tags: grammar

I'm writing an email to a nurse, asking her if my kid's immunizations have been complete or not. I don't know which word I should use, complete or completed. And what tense should I use, present tense or present perfect tense?

The email I wrote like this:" Hixxx, I got the information that children without completed immunizations will not be able to start school. I'd like to know if my kid's immunizations are complete or not."

Please help with that. Many thanks!

Comment: What you wrote is fine.  There are fussy people who will demand something different, but the above text would be clearly understood by any native English speaker.

Comment: In the first example, complete is an adj. (Like the flowers are beautiful). The second one is the passive voice of "XYZ completes immunizations."

Comment: @HotLicks: Comment worth thinking.

Answer (score 1):

A more technical answer compared the top-level comment:

X is *complete* suggests more that something is entire and every object is included. See "My list is *complete*," meaning that everything I want on my list is actually on the list.

X is *completed* suggests that a task has be executed to "completion," à la, "I completed the job."

However, these are entirely pedantic definitions. You often hear/see people say "The job is complete." even though they mean the job has been finished.

Answer (score -1):

If the immunizations were completed then they have been taken to the end of the procedure of immunization and they are therefore  complete immunizations, that is to say made thouroughly; if they are complete, then, necessarily, the procedures for performing them have been completed. Therefore both statements are equivalent as far as the outcome. You can use the past tense tense, also.

- Hixxx, I got the information that children without completed immunizations will not be able to start school. I'd like to know if my kid's immunizations **were** complete or not."

Comment: I might be off here, but it seems like "were complete" implies that the immunizations were in a state of completion at some past point, but currently are not. It would make more sense to leave it as present tense, such that, currently, the immunizations are in a state of completion.

Comment: @FelixJen I can't figure out that one. It seems to me that whether something has been performed in its entirety or not is a question about how complete it is or in other words, whether it has been completed or not, and that a state of completion is another matter that involves the act of making complete what is not; I don't see how this possible separate state can be implied: a completion might be possible or on the contrary, impossible.

Comment: I might be envisioning a slightly different scenario where this subtly may come into play. For example, in this instance, if the immunization requirements were updated after the immunizations *were complete*. In this scenario, the individual , **currently** may be missing some immunizations, thus the immunizations *are not complete*. Hence, if you say the immunizations *are complete*, this suggests, regardless of prior modifications to the requirements of completion, a present state of completeness.

Comment: I feel like the gloss might be on the subtle shade of meaning that *was* and *is* can take on. See, e.g., https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/283758/proper-use-of-was-vs-is

Comment: @FelixJen I don't think the slight difference between "is" and "was" is of any consequence and first of all I can't grasp what your updating scenario changes: in such a situation the parties have to be informed, otherwise confusion is likely, and they will therefore make clear what criterion of completeness is at hand.

Comment: Completely valid point that the parties must be informed first and foremost, and in this context, such a subtle distinction between the two verbs is lacking consequence. If the criterion of completeness was known and agreed, then I suppose is/was would not cause any confusion. I was simply approaching this from a more pedantic sense of the *past tense*: "The past indicative denotes an act . . . that existed at some *explicit* or *implicit* point in the past." *CMoS* § 5.130. Rather, perhaps *present-perfect* may be an even better fit: "condition that continues to the present." *CMoS* § 5.132.

Comment: A basic point here is that immunizations are not complete or completed, they’re either up to date or not, given the age of the person.  Some immunizations first given to children need to be updated periodically, no doubt depending on the medical practice in the jurisdiction.

Comment: @Xanne This very pertinent comment puts back the discussion at a point from which perhaps it  shouldn't have swerved: immunization is achieved through periodic injections of vaccine and half-shots are never a possibility.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.